# Tranposing dataset in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

May I know how to transpose this data into the format I want in excel

[image]

The current method I had done is manually copy and paste, but i have to convert from a 15 rows x 6 columns data into a 3 rows x 30 columns data. I have to repeat for 7 times for a case study and I have 100 different case studies.

This is part of the actual table I need:

[image]

Comment: Re "*to convert from a 15 rows x 6 columns data into a 5 rows x 30 columns data*", 15 rows x 6 columns is 90 cells, but 5 rows x 30 columns is 150 cells?

Comment: sorry. Is 3row x 30 column

Comment: Is your example exact, i.e. you want to copy the first three rows (numbers 1-9) then place the next three rows (10-18) to the right of them?

Comment: Transpose usually means take 3 cells in a row and change to 3 cells in a column or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that is the format I want, and this is just a small part of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transform Data

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:C7,result_rows,3,
    sr,ROWS(data),
    sc,COLUMNS(data),
    tc,sr*sc,
    ts,SEQUENCE(tc)-1,
    dn,tc*result_rows/sr,
WRAPCOLS(INDEX(TOCOL(data),
    MOD(INT(ts/result_rows),sc)
        +sc*MOD(ts,result_rows)+1
        +dn*INT(ts/dn)),
    result_rows))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using REDUCE and HSTACK:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(5,,1,3),LAMBDA(b,a,HSTACK(b,INDEX(A2:F16,a,1):INDEX(A2:F16,a+2,6)))),,1)
```

[image]

Using LET() to make it a bit more dynamic:

```
=LET(
    data,A2:F16,
    rws,3,
    clms,COLUMNS(data),
    steps,INT(ROWS(data)/rws),
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(steps,,1,rws),LAMBDA(b,a,HSTACK(b,INDEX(data,a,1):INDEX(data,a+rws-1,clms)))),,1))
```

Now you can change the data range and the number of rows in the output and it will do the rest.

Comment: if now I have 105 rows x 6 columns of data, and I want to have the same process but will start at a new row (row 4 (3n+1)) after reaching the 30 columns. (making a 21 rows x 30 columns)

Comment: Then use the second formula and put the range after `data,` and change the `3` to `21` after `rws,`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula, may be it can be made more shorter:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:C7,
     --TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("/",,BYROW(MAP(WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),3),
     LAMBDA(r,ARRAYTOTEXT(INDEX(a,r,)))),LAMBDA(r,ARRAYTOTEXT(r)))),", ","/"))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

While you have a nice non-lambda solution from VBasics2008, you may also have data where the number of rows are not a multiple of the n-number of rows you want to pivot/transpose. In that case you could use this:

```
=LET(a,A1:C12,
     n,3,
     r,ROWS(a),
     h,CEILING(r,n),
     c,COLUMNS(a),
IFERROR(INDEX(a,
              INT(SEQUENCE(,(h*c)/n,0,1/c))*n+SEQUENCE(n),
              MOD(SEQUENCE(n,(h*c)/n,0),c)+1),""))
```

[image]

Or this for using with lambda:

```
=LET(a, A1:C11,
     n, 3,
REDUCE( TAKE(a,n), SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP((ROWS(a)-n)/n,0)),
LAMBDA( x,         y,
HSTACK(x,
       IFERROR(INDEX(a,y*n+SEQUENCE(n),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(a))),"")))))
```

Comment: Wonderful. That's definitely more reasonable. You could recycle the `r` variable though but I guess it's more readable with it.

Comment: @VBasic2008 you mean skipping the `ROWS(a)` as a variable and use `CEILING(ROWS(a),n)` at once? That could shorten the formula, but I don't think it affects calculation.
I also added a possible LAMBDA solution.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't, just nitpicking. Your *REDUCE* addition is also nice. The issue we both didn't consider is that if a cell is blank, it will return 0. Arrrgh, how I hate that. Sure, it's a simple fix but then if you also want to account for possible error values, it's not that simple anymore.

Comment: `=LET(a,A1:C11,n,3,REDUCE(TAKE(a,n),SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP((ROWS(a)-n)/n,0)),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,LET(r,INDEX(a,y*n+SEQUENCE(n),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(a))),IFERROR(IF(r="","",r),""))))))` ? I'm with you there: Why did they design it to show 0 in case of blank in the first place.

Comment: If you want to keep it as-is, `IFERROR(IF(r="","",r),r)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the last `r` would show error values for the last row(s) of the index-spill in case of non-divisible row numbers, hence the `""`.